# multiple returns vs return variable in python

Tags: python

I am a beginner programmer using python and I wonder what the best practice is for returns in a function. I have a lot of conditions, but as soon as one of them is true, I want to kill the function and return a bool value.
say, we have:

```
a)
def foo():
    if condition1:
        return True
    if condition2:
        return True
    if condition3:
        return True
    return False

b)
def foo():
    bar = False
    if condition1:
        bar = True
    elif condition2:
        bar = True
    elif condition3:
        bar = True
    return bar
```

Is one way better than another? Why? Or is this some utter junk and should be implemented in a completly different way? Is it different in other languages than in python (or, is there a "pythonic" way)?
Thank you all in advance for your answers.
BTW, is there a tag for best practice, or something like that?

Comment: I doubt this is specific to Python, and there's a lot to find when searching for "early return". It's also very situation specific, such as how clear or how hidden the early returns are. And, in your case: `if condition1 or condition2 or condition3: return True; return False` might even clearer.

Comment: Both are fine. You should use whatever is more readable in your case.

Comment: For long functions it can be easier to read using a single return. But maybe breaking those longer functions up is a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first version is more Pythonic in my opinion, it could be written like this instead though:

```
return condition1 or condition2 or condition3
```

Comment: If there's any possibility that any of the conditions aren't `bool`, you're better off casting the result: `return bool(condition1 or condition2 or condition3)`.

Comment: @MarkRansom `return any((condition1, condition2, condition3))`

Comment: in this case, condition1 will check. If true, will it immediatly be return True, or do the other conditions need check anyways? I believe C has something like fast evaluation, do we have it here?

Comment: @JaroStamov yes, there is. You can even use it as some kind of `None` check, for instance: `return item and item.property or default`

Answer (score 3):

Both `a.)` and `b.)` are valid. For languages with resource management like C, or debugging and wanting to break in only one place, the preference  is `b.)`. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from.
For Python and other languages it is standard to use either. See [Should a function have only one return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement)

Comment: Can you elaborate on this for me; is there a way to see this? It returned at `return`, how would I see which `if/elif` case caused `bar = True`?

Comment: @roganjosh It doesn't tell you which condition was true. But if you want to set a breakpoint or add a print statement before the function returns, you only have to put it in one place.

Comment: @Barmar Actually, I see that point. Fair, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use the "bar" variable and you don't need to create it.

Other ways:

```
def f():
    return condition1 or condition2 or condition3

def f2():
    return any([condition1, condition2, condition3])
```